# Best approach to disable elements

Tags: html, css

What is the best approach to disable elements such as buttons and form inputs?

I am going to use a collection of buttons with different styling (demonstrated in the image below) as a scenario to better explain my question.

[image]

The old-fashioned way which I used to disable these buttons was to apply the following CSS to every and each one of them.

```
.button.disabled,
.button.disabled:hover {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #666C80 !important;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2) !important;
}

.button.button-outlined.disabled,
.button.button-outlined.disabled:hover {
  color: #2B508F;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #2B508F;
}
```

Obviously, each button has different style rules, which means the .disabled styling rules will have to change every time we change them in the normal style.

For example, if I wanted to change the border-radius or add shadow to the button, I will have to apply the default of these to the disabled style section of that button as well.

Before asking this question on here, I had a play trying to solve this issue myself by attempting the following approach:

[image]

```
/*Disbiled settings*/
.button.disabled, .button.disabled:hover, 
button.disabled, button.disabled:hover,
button:disabled, button:disabled:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
    border: 1px solid inherit !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}

.disabled:after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0; top: 0; 
    bottom: 0; right: 0;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    pointer-events: normal;
}
```

So, when `.disabled` is applied to the element, an invisible box will be placed above the element and cover it completely using ":after" - just as the code above explains.

This method should work as having this invisible box above the element, should disable clicking or hovering the elements behind it, it should simply 'disable' the :hover effect. But it is not! What I am missing?

I have put a JSfiddle together here: https://jsfiddle.net/pdnxreyd/1

**FYI:**

1) The following JS snippet is used to disabled clicking on disabled elements:

```
//Prevent Clicking on .active & disabled links
    $('.active, .noLink > a, a[href="#"], .disabled, disabled').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

2) I really just want to apply opacity: 0.8; and cursors: not-allowed to all .disabled elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to understand what you are asking in your question from what I understand there are 2 possible questions you are asking.

#### 1. How to remove touch/click events from the button when it is disabled

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/

pointer events will disable the click event via css

```
.disabled {
  ...
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

#### 2. A generic style that can be applied to all disabled button styles.

Simply reducing the opacity of the element may be sufficient to signify that the button is disabled. This will dim the button no matter what styles are applied to it.

```
.disabled {
  opacity: .4;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the only thing missing is how to also add cursor: not-allowed - that is the missing part which I can't seem to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

The "best" approach I can see is to make use of SCSS and to define the

```
.button
{
  background-color: $buttonColor;

    &.disabled
    {
        cursor: not-allowed;
        background-color: desaturate( $buttonColor, 50% );

    }
}
```

You can obviously make a method to pass the color in parameter.

Otherwise keeping the traditional approach, an idea is to keep the background color white or gray and to add the real button components on top. Then adjust the opacity of this overlay. In this manner the button will be shaded but not transparent.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on when and why you want to disable the buttons. One of the ways is to create another element which 'hovers' on the button with greater z-index. See the fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/myphdgLc/

Basically you will use a structure like below :

```
<div class="cont">
    <span class="disable"> </span>
    <a class="button disabled" href="#">Button</a>
</div>
```

With the following CSS :

```
.cont{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
.disable{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:9999;
    background:transparent;
}
.disable:hover{
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Of course, you can use JavaScript to dynamically to append these new elements before and after a specific button. This method will automatically stop the click event as well, so you won't need the JavaScript function for that.